# Edit file contents of folder before compress it

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I want to compress the contents of a folder. The catch is that I need to modify the content of a file before compressing it. The modification should not alter the contents in the original folder but should be their in the compressed file

So far I was able to figure out altering file contents using `sed` command-

```
sed 's:/site_media/folder1/::g' index.html >index.html1
```

where `/site_media/folder1/` is the string which I want to replace with empty string. Currently this code is creating  another file named `index.html1` as I don't want to make the changes inplace for the file `index.html`.

I tried pipelining this command with the zip command as follows

```
sed 's:/site_media/folder1/::g' folder1/index.html > index1.html |zip zips/folder1.zip folder1/
```

but I am not getting any contents when I unzip the file `folder1.zip`. Also the modified file in the compressed folder should be named `index.html (and not index.html1)`

Comment: so any feedback from my answer?

Comment: It kind of work partially. Actually what I need is to change the contents of file "index.html" in the compressed folder (the resulting folder which I get by running zip command) without copying the modified content to index1.html (in the same folder). Therefore I tried pipe-lining sed with zip command in the first place (was unsuccessful though)

Answer (score 0):

You want to do two things. Then, say `command1 && command2`. In your case:

```
sed '...' folder1/index.html > index1.html && zip zips/folder1.zip folder1/
```

If you pipe commands, you use the output of the first to feed the second, which is something you don't want in this case.